# ExtJS freeze on Safari 14

Tags: extjs, safari, freeze, extjs6

We have a problem using ExtJS with safari 14.
We can easily reproduce the issue in the sencha documentation for that just click on the following link : https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#remote-combo.

Once you're on the page just click somewhere outside the ExtJS form and your safari will freeze forever... (in the red area visible on the screenshot for instance)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX0uE.png

This is a big problem for us because our interfaces are not usable anymore on safari.
Does anyone already faced this problem and have a solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to workaround it this way

```
Ext.getBody().dom.addEventListener(
    'pointerdown',
    function(e) {
        if(Ext.fly(e.target).getAttribute('data-ref') === 'innerCt') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Hello,

It's not working the browser freeze before entering the function :(